Pulseaudio need user session login
I have a Python script that utilizes PulseAudio to control audio volumes, as well as handle mute and unmute commands. This script is set to run at system startup and is designed to function in conjunction with NoMachine for remote management.
The challenge I am facing is that the script does not execute until a user manually logs into the system. However, the device is intended to operate in a headless mode, and I need the script to run immediately upon boot, without requiring manual login.
Could you please advise on how to ensure the script runs as intended on a headless system,  becaus3 I will not make a user login each time ?
I appreciate your assistance and guidance.
Make the script running on boot without need to user login

I suggest you give it a try and post your solution or any issues you face during the process.
For me, I believe a systemd service would be suitable in your case. Here’s how you can set it up:

Create a systemd service file:
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/pulseaudio_script.service


Add the following content:
[Unit]
Description=PulseAudio Control Script
After=network.target sound.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /path/to/your/script.py
Restart=always
User=<your_user>        ### replace by your username
Environment=XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
Environment=PULSE_RUNTIME_PATH=/run/user/1000/pulse
Environment=DISPLAY=:0

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target


Enable and start the service:
sudo systemctl enable pulseaudio_script.service
sudo systemctl start pulseaudio_script.service



